# Only Sensitive values IN GetFile Processor?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I have created the processor using RestAPI(Nifi-1.0) in windows.

Post:    /process-groups/{id}/processors

Json:

```
{
"revision":{"version":0},
"component":
{
   "name":"GetFile",
   "type":"GetFile"
}
}
```

It creates processor with empty attributes in UI. But if I click "+" to add new attribute in UI.Then it will created property but all property are only sensitive value set.

I can't able to create property without sensitive set.

Comment: This question needs clarification. Are you saying that when you view the UI, you can add new attributes, but it only persists attributes marked as sensitive? Or are you saying that you want to add some other property?

Comment: @Andy it only persists attributes marked as sensitive only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type in the request needs to be fully qualified. Sounds like when you're attempting to create the component, it's actually creating a generic component used when the type is unknown.

If you use the UI and open Developer Tools in your browser you should be able to see an example of this.

Comment: Thanks Matt i have specified type as "GetFile" this is problem for create processor with sensitive value set.If i change it into "org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetFile" It create processor with attributes